# Use straightedge (no compass) to find the centers of two intersecting circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

We can use the compass and straightedge to find the center of one circle.

We have proven we cannot find the center of a circle with straightedge alone (see: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/impossible/straightedge.shtml)

But if we are given two intersecting circles, can we find the centers of both circles?

Comment: The perpendicular bisectors of two chord of a circle which have angle less than $180^o$ intersect on center of the circle. There is no need for a compass to do that. We have a common chord it's perpendicular bisector connects the centers of two circles. All we need is to draw two chords, one in each circle,  having angle with common chord and draw their perpendicular bisectors.

Comment: @sirous how do you draw the perpendicular bisectors of a segemnt with just a straightedge? if you can do that, you can find the center of any circle? Which was proven impossible in my link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For a chord $HG$ of the first circle, we can construct two parallel chords $EF$ and $IJ$ of the second circle. Since $EFIJ$ is an inscribed trapezoid, $LK$ is a perpendicular bisector of its base and passes through a circle centre. Two of those give you the centre.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT:

If we can draw common tangents without compass, then they intersect in P. We find mid point C of common chord AB and conect it to P. The centers of the circles are on PC and it's extension.[image]

Now we draw perpendiculars from tangent point D and E , they intersect with PC in M and N which are centers of two circles.

Comment: It's not clear how to construct the common tangent.